# Regex validation for phone number in Laravel

Tags: regex, laravel, validation

I have written a regex to validate a phone number like `+1(320)-924-2043`

```
regex:/^\+1\(?([0-9]{3})\)-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

But it's not working.

Comment: @sanjay: musefan's answer is right.

Comment: @HirenGohel Thanks

Comment: Not to thanks me, thanks to @musefan  :)

Comment: Thanks both of you :) @HirenGohel

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like you just need to remove the `(?` part and the matching `)`

```
/^\+1\([0-9]{3}\)-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/
```

This will match `+1(320)-924-2043` correctly

Comment: My regex work perfect i have check it on regex checker. but your also work

Answer (score 0):

There is good service where you can check your regex. Link http://regexr.com/.

this regularexp work for this pattern: `/\+1\((\d){3}\)-(\d){3}-(\d){4}/`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex works : `/^+1(?([0-9]{3}))-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/`

```js
var component = {
    input   : $('input[name="number"]'),
    mensage : {
        fields  : $('.msg'),
        success : $('.success'),
        error   : $('.error')
    }
},
    regex  = /^\+1\([0-9]{3}\)-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$/;

component.input.keyup(function () {
    component.mensage.fields.hide();
    regex.test(component.input.val()) ? component.mensage.success.show() : component.mensage.error.show();
});
```

```css
.msg {
    display: none;
}
.error {
    color: red;
}
.success {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number" name="number" type="text" class="required" /> 
<span class="msg error">You shall not pass!</span>
<span class="msg success">You can pass!</span>
```

Comment: great it's work but my regex also work but i don't where error is.